# Navigation bar, inline show issue

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem with navigation bar on my website. Navigation bar is created as inline list with "a" elements. It looks and works fine until I zoom the website. When I zoom, elements of the list collapses in two rows. Is there any way to make inline list static?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<div id="NavigationDiv">
 <ul id="NavigationList">
    <li><a>Naslovnica</a></li>
    <li><a>Automatizacija</a></li>
    <li><a>Antistatika</a></li>
    <li><a>Machine Vision</a></li>
    <li><a>Steper motori</a></li>
    <li><a>Proizvodi</a></li>
    <li><a>Industrija</a></li>
    <li><a>Zastupstva</a></li>
    <li><a>Mogućnosti</a></li>
    <li><a>Kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>
```

```
 <style> 
#NavigationList{margin-top:5px; position:absolute; top:110px;}
ul#NavigationList li{font-family:calibri; font-size:22px; color:white; display:inline; list-style-type:none; padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px;}
ul#NavigationList li a:hover {color: #f9b233;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add white-space: nowrap; into your #NavigationList

```
#NavigationList{margin-top:5px; position:absolute; top:110px; white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: Man, You work fast! I added as You told and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hvxdqut/)**

```
#NavigationList {       
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

now you will get scrolling even if you zoom

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your code like so to make the container ul inline-block.

```
 <style>

    * {color: black;}

    #NavigationList {
        margin-top:5px;
        position:absolute;
        top:110px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    ul#NavigationList li {
        font-family:calibri;
        font-size:22px;
        color:white;
        display:inline;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding-right:5px;
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    ul#NavigationList li a:hover {color: #f9b233;}

</style>
```

Hope this answers your questions